# savedInstanceState referring wrong values when invoking an external Intent

Tags: android

I am pretty new to Android development and having basic knowledge.

I have 3 activities. In Activity1, i have 3 variables say passCount, failCount,skipCount and a bundle. I am passing these values to Activity2 and onCreate method i am able to get these values properly.

Following is my code to save these values:

```
 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        savedInstanceState.putInt("noPassed",nPassed);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("noFailed",nFailed);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("noSkipped",nSkipped);
        savedInstanceState.putBundle("com.abc.xyz",extras);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        nPassed=savedInstanceState.getInt("noPassed");
        nFailed= savedInstanceState.getInt("noFailed");
        nSkipped=savedInstanceState.getInt("noSkipped");
        extras=savedInstanceState.getBundle("com.abc.xyz");
    }
```

Here is my onCreate() method of Activity2:

```
  if(savedInstanceState==null) {
            Log.d("onCreate","I am onCreate");
            extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            nPassed = extras.getInt("noPassed");
            nFailed = extras.getInt("noFailed");
            nSkipped = extras.getInt("noSkipped");
        }else
        {
            nPassed=savedInstanceState.getInt("noPassed");
            nFailed= savedInstanceState.getInt("noFailed");
            nSkipped=savedInstanceState.getInt("noSkipped");
            extras=savedInstanceState.getBundle("com.abc.xyz");
        }
```

Now upon clicking on one a link i am navigating to Activity3. Here i am switching to Activity2 by clicking on close button.

The problem i see here, always the savedInstanceState is null and getting error                 **extras = getIntent().getExtras();** in onCreate method and unable to proceed further. What i am missing?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.udayrepo.ss/com.abc.xyz.Summary_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Where do you save the values?

Comment: My understanding is that, on clicking on a link in Activity2, the onSaveInstanceState is called and values are saved with the bundle. Is my understanding is wrong?